# How do I hide google maps snippets by adding them to the marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I use google maps and want to add snippets, but I do not want to show them to me. I tried everything, but I did not find a solution. Maybe someone knows how to hide user snippets?

```
        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter(){

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_maps_window_info, null);
            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_marker_title);

            title.setText(marker.getTitle());

            return v;
        }

    });
```

Adding marker

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .title("TITLE NAME")
                            .icon(markerIcon)
                            .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                            .snippet("TEST") /* <- hide */
                    );
```

Need hide snippets just from maps info windows

Thank you! :)

Comment: **I want to pass this text and transfer it to another activity via snippets, but I can not succeed on the user.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
if(marker.getSnippet().equals(true)) {
                        marker.setSnippet(null);
                    }
```

OR

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                marker.hideInfoWindow();
            }
        });
```

Comment: `map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                marker.hideInfoWindow();
            }
        });`

Comment: Joyson, Yes I've tried it before and it did not help. But it does not work.

Comment: Try `@Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_maps_window_info, null);
            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_marker_title);

            title.setText(marker.getTitle());
marker.setSnippet("");
            return v;
        }`

Comment: I want to pass this text and transfer it to another activity via snippets, but I can not succeed on the user.

Comment: Make a global var then put on inside infoContents var = marker.getsnippet(); lastly, access the global var

Answer (score 0):

create a custom info window.

Class:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.app.myrydeo.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

public class CustomInfoWindow implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    View myView;

    public CustomInfoWindow(Context context) {
        myView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        TextView txtPickupTitle = myView.findViewById(R.id.txtPickupInfo);
        txtPickupTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:padding="10dp">
        
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/home"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPickupInfo"
                android:text="Pickup Here"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

On your map activity:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindow(this));
}
```

What this does is it replaces the default info window but does not remove the snippet called. So where you call your marker, call the snippet in that marker and it will still retain its value.